# What are the salary bands specifically for lecturer/senior lecturer/reader/professor in the UK?

Tags: career-path, professorship, united-kingdom, salary

This question is related to this question [Academic position salaries in the UK](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45532/academic-position-salaries-in-the-uk) (and to some extent to this question too: [Academic rank equivalence between the UK and the US systems](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48977/academic-rank-equivalence-between-the-uk-and-the-us-systems/49026#49026)), but my question is more specific.
What salary bands in http://www.ucu.org.uk/index.cfm?articleid=2210, for example, corresponds to that for a lecturer, senior lecturer, reader and professor positions? In the salary scales in this website, the grading just runs from 1 to 51, but doesn't specify what positions they correspond to.

Answer (score 5):

How the titles map onto the grading is not fixed precisely - I've seen it vary by a couple of points across the country, but my institution has lecturer as 30-43, SL/Reader as 44-52 (yes, 52 - not covered by that UCU scale). Professors are not on that scale.

Comment: What is the fine grading between Senior Lecturer and Reader scales? According to an answer to this question: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48977/academic-rank-equivalence-between-the-uk-and-the-us-systems/49026#49026, these two positions are different in the UK. 
Or, is the grading for a Senior Lecturer somewhere inside 30-43?

Comment: Again this is institution dependent, but at most places I know the only distinction is in role (Readers are more research focused), not in salary.

Comment: But there should be salary difference between lecturer and senior lecturer? 30-43 seems a long range compared to 44-52.

Comment: There's a split (often informal, again institution dependent) between "Lecturer A" and "Lecturer B", with the former covering 30-34 and the latter 35-43. A number of places only appoint at Lecturer B and above. There's a substantial salary difference between L and SL.

Comment: "There's a substantial salary difference between L and SL." - that's exactly is confusing me here. Where does the salary level for SL (on an average over institutions) start? And where is the distinction in the salary level between SL and Reader?

Comment: Or, asking it differently, if I am offered a 'beginning SL level' (higher than L, but just the starting level of SL) position in a UK university, what salary level should I expect?

Comment: Beginning L either point 30 (L "A") or point 35 (L "B"). Beginning SL point 44. At present there's a roughly 30% pay increase from point 35 to point 44.